# Set Simple Data Format Programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to change through a Radio Dialog date formats. I wrote this code.

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, load(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


                     switch(item)
                     {
                         case 0:
                             dataFormat = "HH/mm/ss YYYY/MM/DD";
                             index = 0;
                             break;
                         case 1:
                             index = 1;
                             break;
                         case 2:
                             index = 2;
                             break;
                         case 3:

                             break;

                     }
                     MyClass class = new MyClass();
                     class.setDateFormat(dataFormat);
                     savePreferences("DataFormat", item);

                     }
                 });

private void savePreferences(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private int load() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int value = sharedPreferences.getInt("DataFormat", 0);

    return value;
}
```

It works well and stores the values properly but when i go to the other class all remain as before (the date format). in other class(MyClass) i've this code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
String data;

    public void setDateFormat(String data) {

        this.data = data;

    }

    public SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {

        if(data != null) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(data);

        }

        else {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy"); 

        }

        return dateFormat;
    }
```

the problem is here. it's return null because through the logs I saw that enters in the else statement. Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: What's a "Radio Dialog"?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need a guard against empty string like so

```
if (data != null && data.length() > 0)
```

I did a full standalone test like so

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
String data = null;

public void setDateFormat(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
    if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(data);
    } else {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
    return dateFormat;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String date = "2014-01-20";
    Question ja = new Question(); // this class
    ja.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        System.out.println(ja.getDateFormat().parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

which outputs

```
Mon Jan 20 00:00:00 EST 2014
```